# dismissViewControllerAnimated is not dissmissing ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

So....I have a View Controller and when I press a button, another View Controller appears:

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:self.controllerSearch animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Inside view controller number 2 is a table view and when a row is selected in a table this code runs:

```
NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)

        NSString *filePath2 = filePath; assert(filePath2 != nil); // Path to first PDF file

        LazyPDFDocument *document = [LazyPDFDocument withDocumentFilePath:filePath2 password:phrase];

        if (document != nil) // Must have a valid LazyPDFDocument object in order to proceed with things
        {
            LazyPDFViewController *lazyPDFViewController = [[LazyPDFViewController alloc] initWithLazyPDFDocument:document];

            lazyPDFViewController.delegate = self; // Set the LazyPDFViewController delegate to self

#if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:lazyPDFViewController animated:YES];

#else // present in a modal view controller

            lazyPDFViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            lazyPDFViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

            [self presentViewController:lazyPDFViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

#endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH
        }
        else // Log an error so that we know that something went wrong
        {
            NSLog(@"%s [LazyPDFDocument withDocumentFilePath:'%@' password:'%@'] failed.", __FUNCTION__, filePath2, phrase);
        }
```

Now I am using LazyPDFKit and it comes with this delegate method:

```
- (void)dismissLazyPDFViewController:(LazyPDFViewController *)viewController
{
    // dismiss the modal view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

I put a break point and I can see my code goes into the delegate method, but the LazyPDFViewController does not go away.

I have tried the following:

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

but that takes me back a few view controllers to far.

Am I missing something?

Additional code in my first view Controller .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *controllerSearch;
```

and in first view controller .m

```
- (UISearchController *)controller {

    if (!_controllerSearch) {

        // instantiate search results table view
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
        LHFileBrowserSearch *resultsController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchResults"];

        // create search controller
        _controllerSearch = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:resultsController];
        _controllerSearch.searchResultsUpdater = self;

        // optional: set the search controller delegate
        _controllerSearch.delegate = self;

    }
    return _controllerSearch;
}
```

Comment: By what means you are going to LazyPDFViewController. Are you pushing view controller over current one or are you presenting view controller?

Comment: I think dismissViewController will work only when you are presentingViewController. If you are pushing view controller, then you need to pop back

Comment: I believe I am pushing view controller over another and pushing LazyPDFViewController the second view controller

Comment: Try this [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: same results, does nothing

Comment: try [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: same result, does nothing

Comment: If `[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` takes you back too far, have you tried
`[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`?

If that doesn't work, I wonder if it has something to do with you setting modal properties on `lazyPDFViewController`?

Comment: same result...it does nothing

Comment: @user979331 You have to add below code for add childVC and RemoveChildVC like this.....
`//add childview
    [self addChildViewController:aVC];
    [self.view addSubview:aVC.view];
    [aVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //remove
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: @vvk Where would I apply this code?

Comment: @vvk your code kinda works, but there are some elements that childVC does not go over, like a navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
- (void)dismissLazyPDFViewController:(LazyPDFViewController *)viewController
{
    // dismiss the modal view controller
    [[viewController presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

your code :
`[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
just went too far.

Comment: You should not need to call the presentingViewController as the call will find it anyway. Apple says "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal." [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)

Answer (score 2):

If you are pushing the view controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:lazyPDFViewController animated:YES];
```

Then the code in the delegate doesn't make sense, because it assumes it is a modal view controller that needs to be dismissed:

```
- (void)dismissLazyPDFViewController:(LazyPDFViewController *)viewController
{
    // dismiss the modal view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

But you've added it to the navigation stack (I assume).

If you can't pop it again from the navigation controller at this point you are missing some code in your example.

Are you sure your delegate is firing on the main thread? Try:

```
- (void)dismissLazyPDFViewController:(LazyPDFViewController *)viewController
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made the demo project based on your situation. And I am not facing any issue with it. So I think there might be some issue regarding how you are presenting the second controller.

In your button click, try this code:

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
          UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
         //idSecondVC is the storyboard id of second view controller
        SecondVC *SecondVC = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idSecondVC"];
       [self presentViewController:SecondVC animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

And in your controller number 2, I just used the above code:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString  *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %ld",indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self openLazyPDF];
}

- (void)openLazyPDF
{
    NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)

    NSArray *pdfs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];

    NSString *filePath = [pdfs firstObject]; assert(filePath != nil); // Path to first PDF file

    LazyPDFDocument *document = [LazyPDFDocument withDocumentFilePath:filePath password:phrase];

    if (document != nil) // Must have a valid LazyPDFDocument object in order to proceed with things
    {
        LazyPDFViewController *lazyPDFViewController = [[LazyPDFViewController alloc] initWithLazyPDFDocument:document];

        lazyPDFViewController.delegate = self; // Set the LazyPDFViewController delegate to self

#if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:lazyPDFViewController animated:YES];

#else // present in a modal view controller

        lazyPDFViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        lazyPDFViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

        [self presentViewController:lazyPDFViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

#endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH
    }
    else // Log an error so that we know that something went wrong
    {
        NSLog(@"%s [LazyPDFDocument withDocumentFilePath:'%@' password:'%@'] failed.", __FUNCTION__, filePath, phrase);
    }
}

#pragma mark - LazyPDFViewControllerDelegate methods

- (void)dismissLazyPDFViewController:(LazyPDFViewController *)viewController
{
    // dismiss the modal view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And for me everything is working fine.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce the issue you should flag this post for closure under the reason "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced."  Do not post an answer that says "I can't reproduce your issue."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to the same macro for present as dismiss. So, you wrote

```
#if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:lazyPDFViewController animated:YES];

#else // present in a modal view controller

            lazyPDFViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            lazyPDFViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

            [self presentViewController:lazyPDFViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

#endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH
```

You thus need

```
#if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    #else // presented in a modal view controller

                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    #endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH
```

It's possible that you have switched off the main thread and you can always add an assert to be check or, as has been suggested, use a dispatch_async to be certain.

`NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread)];`

I prefer the assert, when I know all the flows through a piece of code, since it shows my assumptions to the future me (or another) and does not leave code that looks like it knows something I do not (oh, they are using dispatch_async onto main so there must be some other thread magic going on deeper down).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)dismissLazyPDFViewController:(LazyPDFViewController *)viewController
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                       {
                           [self dismissLazyPDFViewController:viewController];
                       });
        return;
    }
    if (viewController.navigationController)
    {
        [viewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```